# MVC 2 route from form GET? Or POST?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a small form with a single textbox and a submit button.

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Tag", FormMethod.Post)
```

In my tag controller i have a method that looks like:

```
public ActionResult Index(string tagText)
```

I'm trying to figure out first how to route this so the resulting URL will look like:

http://mydomain.com/Tag/tagText

And i guess i would also like to have this controller handle those types of URLs and return my view the same as if it was posted from the form i've shown above. I am a newb so thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see of your post you want the user to end up at a URL where the last bit is what they actually put in a text box. To do this you need your ActionResult to send

`return RedirectToAction("Tag", new {tagText=tagText} )`

then have a route which maps "/Tag/{tagText}".